# Making line graphs in black and white

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I'm making a line graph with about ten lines or so, and I want each line to be distinguishable in black and white.  Is there a way to "automatically" give each grouping a different line structure (i.e. dashed, dotted, thickness), similar to how you could do the same thing with different colors?  It doesn't matter what these are, just something to make them distinguishable.

Edit: I'm looking for something a little better than

```
aes(linetype=group)
```

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with `aes(linetype = group)`?

Comment: with over four lines or so, it becomes a little hard to tell the lines apart

Comment: That's a good sign that you shouldn't be using line type to distinguish between groups. Try faceting.

Comment: If you can come up with 10 distinguishable linetypes, you can set them with `scale_linetype_manual`. The default palette of linetypes in ggplot has 13 entries, so it may be possible.